# Trying to get array of keys of a json file in godot

Tags: arrays, json, godot

I'm trying to get a array of keys inside a json file so I can use it to determine how many items the crafting recipe has eg: getting the keys in Iron Breastplate. Problem is I get an error when trying to use the .keys() method. Any insight is appreciated, thank you.

[image: Text]

Error occurs at line 65
[image: Text]

Comment: I can see two things that I think you didn't: The `recipes` dictionary only has two items, which makes me think the problem goes back to where it was populated, but I can't see that code. The json is missing a comma, which I guess is why not all items got into the dictionary. And for advice: 1. Use an editor with syntax highlighting, there are plenty of free options for Windows. 2. The place you get an error, is just where it broke, not the source of the problem. 3. Take a break if you need it, and don't forget to read.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'll also look into getting a decent editor hopefully that helps me avoid mistakes like this